# Replace the QTY of the product in the cart on "add to cart" rather than increment

Tags: product, magento2.3, cart, addtocart

How to replace the quantity of the product in the cart instead of increment?

**Current behaviour:**
From the product page:

- Add 5 qty of product A
- Add 2 qty of product A (add product again)
- The cart qty of product A is now 7

**Desired behaviour:**
From the product page:

- Add 5 qty of product A
- Add 2 qty of product A (add product again)
- The cart qty of product A is now 2

Comment: you want your firstly added product A deleted when adding second time same item?

Comment: If that's the way to go, then yes. Unless there is another option to replace and not remove and re-add.

Comment: if the product is simple and has no options then you can go with a simple qty update of the current item, otherwise, remove and add is the best one.

Comment: Have you tried using any plugin or observer?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I was hoping for some advise from here on how to approach the problem. I need to consider the stock management too. However, my initial thought was to go down the observer route.